# Argand diagram and minimum value

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm asked to plot the following complex number inequalities, I managed to plot the second one(PS see this attached img)

- $|z-1|\leq |z-i|$
- $|z-(2+2i) |\leq 1$

PS help me plot the first inequality and calculate the $|z|$ for the point in this region for which $arg~z$ is least.

Any help is greatly appreciated. (Also any **book/web reference** to learn more about these type of questions and concepts will be of great help)

Thanks,
Arif

Comment: If it ever becomes too difficult just imagine everything in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then translate back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=a+ib$.

First, the two absolute values are

$$|z-1|=\sqrt{(a-1)^2+b^2} \text{ and } |z-i|=\sqrt{a^2+(b-1)^2}.$$

We have the following inequality then

$$a^2-2a+1+b^2\le a^2+b^2-2b+1$$

or

$$-2a\le -2b$$

or $$a\ge b.$$

That is, the first inequality holds for those complex numbers whose real part is greater or equal than their imaginary par.

As far as the second inequality we have

$$|z-(2+2i)|=\sqrt{(a-2)^2+(b-2)^2}.$$

So we have the following inequality

$$(a-2)^2+(b-2)^2\le 1$$

which holds inside the unit circle centered at $2+i2$.

The following two figure depicts the two regions

[image]

The third figure depicts the common region in red. The red line is tangent to the circle.

The angle between the tangent line and the Real axis is the smallest argument belonging to complex numbers satisfying both of the inequalities.

Further edit:

The length of the segment (the absolute value of the complex number sought) joining the origin and the tangent point is $\sqrt7$ as explained by the figure below

[image]

Comment: Yes, common region will satisfy both the inequalities, and I want to  a calculate $|z|$ where $z~$ lies in the common region and for which $arg z $ is least. How to go about now ?. I'm also looking for some resources that help me answer such type of question.

Comment: Oh, yes. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @Arif: Do you need further help?

Comment: Got it! , I would like to know about resources (any book/web references) that can help me develop such concepts, many a time question on greatest value is also asked. PS assist

Comment: Got it! , I would like to know about resources (any book/web references) that can help me develop such concepts, as in how will I come to know that it has to tangent and how to go about if greatest value of |z| is asked instead, PS help.

Comment: @Arif: There is a comment to your question. "If it ever becomes too difficult just imagine everything in $\mathbb R^2$, then translate back." I  add to this that if we talk about addition, multiplication by a scalar, arguments of complex numbers, we can go back to our natural intuition we developed in plane geometry and in 2D vectors. If you've solved many problems related to complex numbers you will learn when the best is to forget about $i$ and think only of vectors. I haven't seen books that devoted much attention to problem solving based on this observation. Or all did but not explicitly.

Comment: fine, if you know ps provide me with some links develop my concept  related to Argand diagram ,  max min value of modulus